# Which CDI scope should be used for DAO and Service classes

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, cdi

I am trying to build application just using JPA, CDI(OpenWebBeans + Deltaspike JPA module), JSF. I am using CDI deployed on Tomcat in a same manner that I am used to use Spring framework. I have DAO called GenericDAOImpl like this(first few lines):

```
public abstract class GenericDaoJpa<T> implements GenericDao<T> {
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(GenericDaoJpa.class);

    @Inject
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    private Class<T> type;
```

The EntityManager is injected using DeltaSpike JPA modulehttp://deltaspike.apache.org/jpa.html. This GenericDao is then inherited by concrete DAO(UserDao etc..) which are used by service classes.

For example UserServiceImpl:

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(UserServiceImpl.class);

    @Inject
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Transactional
    public void saveUser(UserDto user) throws UserServiceException {
        try {
            User u = new User(user);
            userDao.create(u);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error while creating user.", e);
            throw new UserServiceException("Error while creating user.");
        }
    }
}
```

Using CDI this way both DAO and Service class will have Dependent scope unlike in spring where they would be singleton. Therefore every client will have new instance injected. 
Should I change scopes on DAO and Service classes to ApplicationScope? But then by the specification I have to make all the classes that are being injected serializable. In case of Dao classes this could be a problem, EntityManager should be then marked as transient? A

I would be glad for any recommendations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@ApplicationScoped` has no relevance to `Serializable`, they're always around and never persist to disk.  `@SessionScoped` will require serialization due to the behavior of HTTP session objects.

I would recommend using a scope as leaving everything dependent will lead to memory leaks (it's never clear when a `@Dependent` object is removed).  If your application is fairly stateless, you can use `@RequestScoped`.  `@ApplicationScoped` you need to consider that multiple clients will connect to your instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In case I use @ApplicationScoped I would expect that as in Spring the bean(singleton scoped in spring) would be accessed many times concurrently. Therefore there would not be any performance problems. Only concern from my part would be to make class thread safe. Or is concurrency not handled automatically by CDI container?

Comment: Concurrency is not handled by the CDI container.